# Children in the Temple

Tags: children, temple-service-avoda

I am currently evaluating a Christian writing called the "Gospel of James" which is not even considered reliable by the Christians. I would like to know whether it is possible that something similar occurred or whether it is a fiction wit no knowledge behind it. This writing states:

> And the child (Mary, the mother of Jesus) became three years old, and Joachim (her father) said: Call for the
> daughters of the Hebrews that are undefiled, and let them take every
> one a lamp, and let them be burning, that the child turn not backward
> and her heart be taken captive away from the temple of the Lord. And
> they did so until they were gone up into the temple of the Lord. And
> the priest received her and kissed her and blessed her and said: The
> Lord has magnified your name ...

The Quran states that she was confined to Zechariah, who was probably a Kohen in Jerusalem (the father of Johanan who is considered a Prophet in Christianity and Islam; Johanan is also mentionned in Josef's Antiquities).

My question:

Are there any traces or hints in Jewish traditions that indicate that children played a certain role in the Temple, or that a child could be given to a priest to have a particular religious education?

And a side-question:

Can the "daughters of the Hebrews that are undefiled" be attributed to anything known?

I would like to encourage contributors who have good knowledge about this subject but do not know anything alike to answer that they have not found any such trace.

Comment: Two things come to mind: a. Children that were raised in purity from birth in a secluded area to be able to prepare the ashes of the Red Heifer. b. Samuel was sent to the Tabernacle in Shiloh to be raised into service and was taken under Eli's wing.

Comment: @Harel13 Thanks. I found the parallel in Samuel (b). Do you have a reference for (a)?

Comment: See [Mishna Parah 3:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Parah.3.2?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi).

Comment: There's a lot of extra stuff here that makes the question off-topic. There's literally no reason to have to mention other religions. A simple "were children allowed in the Temple" or "what role did children play in Temple service" would suffice. I suggest you edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @ezra Mentioning other religions does not make a question off topic.